# Circular SKShapeNode is displayed as square when used in SceneKit overlaySKScene when using fillColor

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, scenekit

I'm trying to build an overlay for my SceneKit scene by using `overlaySKScene`. But for some reason a circular `SKShapeNode` will show up as squares as soon as I set a `fillColor`.

The same node will show up correctly when used with a `SKView`.

Simple Playground example (needs "Run in Full Simulator"):

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit
import SceneKit
import XCPlayground

let skScene = SKScene(size: CGSizeMake(500, 300))
skScene.scaleMode = .AspectFit

let node = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 50)
node.position = CGPoint(x: 250, y: 150)
node.fillColor = SKColor.redColor()
node.strokeColor = SKColor.grayColor()
skScene.addChild(node)

let scnScene = SCNScene()
let scnView = SCNView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 500, height: 300))
scnView.scene = scnScene
scnView.overlaySKScene = skScene

XCPShowView("Live View 1", scnView)

let skView = SKView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 500, height: 300))
skView.presentScene(skScene)

XCPShowView("Live View 2", skView)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While writing this I found the solution. I create the SKScene programmatically and I have to explicitly set `shouldEnableEffects`, `backgroundColor` and `blendMode`.

```
    skScene.shouldEnableEffects = true
    skScene.backgroundColor = SKColor.clearColor()
    skScene.blendMode = .Alpha
```

Comment: It works perfectly in the Watch simulator but when I try to set the shouldEnableEffects property to true and try to compile it on the real Watch, it crashes with a "Program ended with exit code: 0" message in the console.